# How to enable File Streaming in existing SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am saving all documents in the database in the form of binary but the main issue is day by day my database size increasing because of users documents. So someone suggested to enable "File streaming" in your database. Suggest some solution.

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to go through the installation again. Choose a feature installation then add features to an existing installation. There will be a tab when you are in the Database Engine Configuration Step called FILESTREAM click that tab then you can enable it.

Comment: The existing data won't be changed.